# Is it dangerous to leave an ssh connection open in a terminal for long periods of time?

Tags: security, ssh

Other than the obvious danger of someone physically coming upon your open computer when you aren't looking and having access to your server, is there any danger if I leave an ssh connection open for a long time (like days and days)?

Comment: It's as secure as the privileges of the user logged into the session you leave open.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  This is what I suspected, but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recent releases of SSH is secure end to end just as @Iain mentions. 
The more pertinent security concern comes from the physical security at your end point. You don't want to walk away from an unlocked PC with domain admin credentials active .. the same goes for your SSH connections. A lot of the developers I used to work with had issues in this regard - they would leave connections open regularly with full sudo rights and leave their workstations unattended.

Comment: ... "And an embarrassing email was sent from their account, somehow, to the entire engineering staff"

Comment: I thought about it more than once.. It was a bit awkward. Before I became the head network engineer I was a junior programmer. Hard to do that from the old boss's account.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's a secure connection end to end.